# Multi-Select Dropdown Issue: SHIFT Key Works Once, Fails on Reuse, Seeking Alternatives

Tags: reactjs

I've added a ***multi-select feature*** that utilizes the **SHIFT** key to the dropdown. It works the first time, but the second time, it only selects one item. I haven't found a solution yet. There are around **2000** data entries in this dropdown. If there's an easier way for convenient selection, please let me know.

DATA:

```
[
     {
        key: 0,
        label: "label1",
        value: "value2"
     },
     {
        key: 2,
        label: "label1",
        value: "value2"
     },
     {
        key: 3,
        label: "label1",
        value: "value2"
     }
 ]
```

CODE:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const AramaSelect = ({ data, insertValues, name, label }) => {
  console.log(data);
  data.sort((a, b) => {
    const labelA = a.label.toLowerCase();
    const labelB = b.label.toLowerCase();
    if (labelA < labelB) return -1;
    if (labelA > labelB) return 1;
    return 0;
  });

  const [val, setVal] = useState([]);
  const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [firstValueIndex, setFirstValueIndex] = useState(null);
  const [secondValueIndex, setSecondValueIndex] = useState(null);
  const [isSelectingRange, setIsSelectingRange] = useState(false);

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 16 && val.length === 2) {
      const firstIndex = data.findIndex((item) => item.value === val[0].value);
      const secondIndex = data.findIndex((item) => item.value === val[1].value);

      if (!isSelectingRange) {
        setFirstValueIndex(firstIndex);
        setSecondValueIndex(secondIndex);
        setIsSelectingRange(true);
      } else {
        setFirstValueIndex(null);
        setSecondValueIndex(null);
        setIsSelectingRange(false);
      }

      const rangeValues = data.slice(
        Math.min(firstIndex, secondIndex),
        Math.max(firstIndex, secondIndex) + 1
      );

      setVal(rangeValues);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, [val, data, firstValueIndex, secondValueIndex, isSelectingRange]);

  const customStyles = {
    option: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      backgroundColor:
        state.data && state.data.value === val[0]?.value
          ? "lightblue"
          : "white", // Change background color for the first selected item
    }),
  };

  const handleChange = (selectedOptions) => {
    const sortedSelectedOptions = selectedOptions.sort((a, b) => {
      const labelA = a.label.toLowerCase();
      const labelB = b.label.toLowerCase();
      if (labelA < labelB) return -1;
      if (labelA > labelB) return 1;
      return 0;
    });

    if (isSelectingRange) {
      setFirstValueIndex(null);
      setSecondValueIndex(null);
      setIsSelectingRange(false);
    }

    setVal(sortedSelectedOptions);
    setMenuIsOpen(true);

    const valEmails = sortedSelectedOptions.map((item) => item.value);
    insertValues(name, valEmails);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const valEmails = val.map((item) => item.value);
    insertValues(name, valEmails);
  }, [val]);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: 800, margin: "20px 0" }}>
      <Select
        options={data}
        isClearable
        isMulti
        menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
        onMenuOpen={() => setMenuIsOpen(true)}
        onMenuClose={() => setMenuIsOpen(false)}
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={val}
        placeholder={label}
        styles={customStyles}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AramaSelect;
```